# Spoiler in a table with CSS selector

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-selectors

I'm trying to build a spoiler in my Table which I can open and close for sub information.

It works if `.spoiler` is a div, but with tr it is only hidden.
Here is my file, maybe someone find my mistake:

```
.spoiler {
    visibility:hidden;
}

.trigger.close {
    display: none;
}

.trigger.open:target {
    display: none;
}

.trigger.open:target + .trigger.close {
    display: inline;
}

.trigger.open:target + .spoiler {    
  visibility: visible;
}

<a href="#spoiler-open-1" id="spoiler-open-1" class="trigger open">Open</a>
<a href="#spoiler-close-1" id="spoiler-close-1" class="trigger close">Close</a>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="spoiler">
         <td>1.1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: From a semantic point of view, it doesn't make sense to create a new row for the spoiler information. Why not build the markup like: `<tr><td>1<div class="spoiler">1.1</div></td></tr>`

Comment: hi dan, well the sub info is not only a number. It will be  many <tr> fields. So your idea will not work or?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mixed up the targets:

```
> .spoiler{display:none} .spoiler:target {display:table-row}
```

Is this jsfiddle what you want?
http://jsfiddle.net/zjkg9w7b/

Comment: i thinks thats the answer :) but why are both links visible?

Comment: there is only one problem. if i use this for 20tables, with one click, all hidden fields will be appear. Do you have an idea how i can fix this?

Comment: You'll have to target by id I'm afraid